# NSURLSession how-to

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am trying to send a post request to sign into a service. I had it working with NSURLConnection but then found out it was depreciated so I tried to switch over to NSURLSession and I have no idea what to do or why my code isn't working. Please note, some of the code is removed for security reasons.

```
-(NSString *)signIn:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password{
NSString *api_sig = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@methodauth.getMobileSessionpassword%@username%@thisismyapisignature", LASTFM_API_KEY, password, username];//API signature

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=auth.getMobileSession&api_key=apikey&format=json&username=%@&password=%@&api_sig=%@", username, password, [api_sig md5]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"response is %@", response);
}];
[task resume];

if (session) {
    NSLog(@"SUCESS");
}else{
    NSLog(@"FAILURE");
}
return nil;
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:    (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
 NSLog(@"data is %@", data);
}
```

I am getting this in the console

```
2015-12-24 15:04:35.624 [21173:761903] SUCESS
2015-12-24 15:04:36.445 [21173:762056] response is <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8f3d0bd9d0> { URL: https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=auth.getMobileSession&api_key=apikey&format=json&username=username&password=password&api_sig=apisig } { status code: 400, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Access-Control-Max-Age" = 86400;
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 58;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Thu, 24 Dec 2015 15:04:35 GMT";
Server = "openresty/1.7.7.2";
} }
```

Comment: The question title should be [HTTP codes how-to](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: I know im getting an error code 400 but i dont know why

Comment: And nobody but you knows what format is expected by your backend. With stubs it is hard to tell, but you might need to verify your parameters to be properly encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is not correct for post.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=auth.getMobileSession&api_key=apikey&format=json&username=%@&password=%@&api_sig=%@", username, password, [api_sig md5]];
```

You should separate your url from your query then post the query to the body as data.

Something like:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/"];
NSString * post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"method=auth.getMobileSession&api_key=someapikey&format=json&username=%@&password=%@&api_sig=%@", username, password, [api_sig md5]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

Comment: Also you url seems wrong. It should end with an action. Something like: `"https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/someAction"`